# Is there a way to create a global component for fullscreen (or directive) that can be enabled/disabled from any component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

So I have been learning a lot about Angular lately and wanted to try something a bit different. I am wanting a fullscreen component that is comprised of a button that can call the browsers fullscreen API.

The problem is, I want this component to be disabled by default and be toggleable for display from any component.

I don't have any code to show because I am honestly unsure of where to start with this. Should I make a directive that calls a fullscreen service, which would have the enable/disable methods?

Do I only need a service with properties and then subscribe to it with the components that want access to the fullscreen component?

I expect that I am overthinking this and that it is as simple as making a component, service, directive and then calling the appropriate methods to enable or disable the component from view.

Any help would really be appreciative!

Answer (score 0):

Can you separate your application into layouts (header,body,footer) and then you could place the button in the header component, so you can enter the full screen from any component, since they will all be in the body component of your app?

Comment: The idea would be that this Fullscreen component would live at the root level of the template (like the header, footer, and body) but any component could choose to disable viewing of the component at a component level

I feel ultimately I am going to just have to include this Fullscreen component manually for each parent container component I want it to have effect on.

Comment: Hmm, you could also broadcast an event from child components that want to use fullscreen, the root component could then show fullscreen if the event was received, and onDestroy lifecycle of the child component you could send an event to disable the fullscreen